# It's possible to clear browsing history using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

It's possible to clear browsing history using javascript?

If yes, how can I do this?

**Note:**
A lot of forums said **no**, but some said **yes**, so I'm lost.

---

**EDIT**

**Note**: I want to clear only the last pages in **mydomain** (random pages in mydomain).

Comment: Would you like to find your browsing history cleared after visiting some random page?

Comment: For what reason do you want to clear the history anyway?

Comment: Because of [this](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/08/richfaces-sessions-eating-memory-analysis-of-a-memory-leak/). I'm having memory leak using RichFaces, so I will disable the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are ways to go about preventing the user from going back a page, but to completely clear your entire browsing history is not possible. let alone deleting any of it

Comment: You said "completely clear your entire browsing history is possible." Did you mean NOT possible?

Comment: yes, yes i did lol, my bad, i originally wrote not impossible, then change it to just possible, my bad

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

That would be a security issue, if it were possible: a website you visit could maliciously delete all your browsing history without your permission.

However, it *is* possible to clear the history in javascript within a google chrome extension. Take a look at [`chrome.history.deleteAll()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#method-deleteAll).

Comment: If script runs in the SAME domain that history page, I don't think that is a security issue. By the way, thanks your anwser! :)

Comment: Ah, so you want a site to clear all of _its_ history entries?

Answer (score 4):

Even if you could, you shouldn't.

Comment: Why I shoundn't? (I edited my question.. is only in my domain)

Comment: It breaks what the user expects, and it would hijack what should purely be a function of the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is a closed box; you can't change files on a clients computer, which is essentially what this would be doing.

So nope, you can't.